# Deploy SQL Server with pre-installed DB using Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a docker image of SQL Server that includes a restored backup of an empty DB using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest AS build
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=myP@ss0rd#
ENV MSSQL_PID=Express

# Have a stage specifically to populate the data directory
FROM build AS data
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY TiPS_v.1.3.4.0.bak .
COPY restore-backup.sql .

RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & sleep 10 \
    && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "myP@ss0rd#" -i /tmp/restore-backup.sql \
    && pkill sqlservr

# Final stage that actually will actually be run.   
FROM build AS release
# Copy the prepopulated data tree, but not the backup file
COPY --from=data /var/opt/mssql/data /var/opt/mssql/data
```

Running a docker container off of that image works fine and I can access the restored DB. But when I try to run using docker-compose with following yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mssql:
    image: tips-db:1.3.4.1
    container_name: "mssql-tips"
    user: root
    restart: always
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    volumes:
      - ./mssql/data/:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./mssql/log/:/var/opt/mssql/log
      - ./mssql/secrets/:/var/opt/mssql/secrets   
    ports:
      - 11433:1433
```

the restored DB is not there anymore. Only system databases are present.

I have only basic understanding of docker. I really can't understand why the .mdf, .ldf files of my Db are not persisted when then container is run. I can only see the files from system databases inside my local `mssql/data` folder.

Is there something I could do so that my restored DB is persisted after the container is run through docker-compose?

Comment: The `volumes:` mount is hiding everything in the image's data directory and replacing it with whatever happens to be in that host directory; it is losing the preloaded data.

Comment: @DavidMaze The host directory is initally empty. After the container starts it is populated with all .mdf, .ldf files from system datatabes (like master, msdb, etc). So these files are copied from the container folder to the host directory. Why doesn't this happen for my database files as well? They are there in /var/opt/mssql/data like all other system db files, right?

Comment: Something in your container logic needs to do that; Docker on its own doesn't (there is one corner case around named volumes that I would avoid).  Does the base image create a new empty database if there's nothing there currently?

Comment: @DavidMaze Script `restore-backup.sql` is restoring the backup copied by `COPY TiPS_v.1.3.4.0.bak`. A new DB is created in the intermediate image. The files of this DB are copied to the image created in the final stage. But these files are lost when volume is mounted.

Comment: Correct, the volume mount hides them.  The contents of the host directory replace everything in the image at container startup time.

Comment: @DavidMaze But in the same directory there are other files as well. How come these files are not lost?

Comment: I would suggest checking out: https://github.com/enriquecatala/mssql-server-samplesdb it has a lot of dockerfiles that you can use a sample.